# MySQL Update if exists else insert - On Duplicate Key confusion

Tags: mysql

I want to write a statement to insert into the database if no record is found and update the existing record if it already exists.

My table is like so:

```
**ID** | Value | UserID | VoteID
   1       10      567      54
   2       19      600      78
```

I want to do the following (written in semi-pseudo):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE UserID = 600 AND VoteID = 78)
  UPDATE table SET Value = 100 WHERE UserID = 600 AND VoteID = 78
ELSE 
  INSERT INTO table (Value, UserID, VoteID) Values(100, 600, 78)
```

How does one use 'On Duplicate Key' in this situation, it at all? 
Thanks

Comment: Is `UserID,VoteID` a unique key?

Comment: As a combination they are unique, but there may be more than one record for each user

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table (Value, UserID, VoteID)
VALUES (100, 600, 78)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Value = 100
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. The value field, userID field and the VoteID field will not be unique.
What makes a record unique is the combination of the UserID and the Vote ID, for example in this case 600 & 78.

Comment: @user1636130 that should still work with `on duplicate key update`.  Did you try it?

Comment: I've tried it, I get a new row inserted each time executed it.

Comment: @user1636130 is there a declaration of `UNIQUE KEY (UserID, VoteID)`?

Comment: No there wasn't, I've looked up how to do that and its working now. Thanks for your help mate!